# Java best structure for 2D matrix of integers?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

What is the best way to store a 2D matrix of integers in Java?

This matrix will be filled in from a data file, which may have different dimensions, so initializing int M[][] = new int[n][m] of some size does not work since we do not know the size of matrix and we will just iterate lines of the file and extract integers from each line (separated by a whitespace inside). So I guess to use an ArrayList of ArrayList to add integers as objects on the fly, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Also it is important to choose the best structure to store such matrix in terms of performance sine I'm going to iterate this matrix and do some computations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start with an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, and then as soon as you've finished reading the file, turn it into an `int[][]` for performance.

Answer (score 5):

As you guessed, it would probably be best to use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` when you are processing the file. If performance is going to be an issue after the fact, it might be prudent to turn it back into a two dimensional array afterwords.

You can add to the two dimensional `ArrayList` matrix like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
matrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
matrix.get(0).add(ROW0Col0Number);
matrix.get(0).add(ROW0Col1Number);
matrix.get(1).add(ROW1Col0Number);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example class that creates and prints a 3x3 Matrix

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        System.out.println(matrix.toString());//print empty matrix
        ArrayList<Integer> row1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        ArrayList<Integer> row2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
        ArrayList<Integer> row3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7,8,9));
        matrix.add(row1);
        matrix.add(row2);
        matrix.add(row3);
        System.out.println(matrix.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the best option is to use a `List<List<Integer>>` to read the file, but I don't believe it is necessary to convert it back to an an `int[][]` after you complete reading. Internally `ArrayList` already uses arrays (hence the name), and the compiler will likely translate `list.get(i).get(j)` to simply `arr[i][j]`, so there is no performance penalty. If you are concerned with space performance, you can use `trimToSize()` to trim the lists after they are built.

On the other hand, it is better to write `A[i][j]` then `A.get(i).get(j)`, so its up to you. I'll write some pseudo-pseudo-code, as I don't know how you plan to fetch elements from the file.

```
List<List<Integer>> mat = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for line in file{
    row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mat.add(row);
    for element in line
        row.add(element);
    row.trimToSize();
}
mat.trimToSize()

//If you really want to convert, and is sure that all rows have the same size...
int[][] A = new int[mat.size()][];
int i=0;
for (List<Integer> row : mat){
    A[i++] = row.toArray(A[i]);
}
```

Comment: Saying that there is no performance penalty with `ArrayList` vs primitive arrays is wrong. Internally ArrayList does use primitive arrays, but there is additional overhead that `ArrayList` does that isn't there with primitive arrays. You will definitely incur differences in performance, its just a matter of measuring if the decrease is worth it.